# How to close ons-sliding menu from push page ons navigator

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

How to close sliding menu from push page navigator in onsen ui and in angularjs ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the docs for splitter and Angular2 with Onsen 2.

https://onsen.io/v2/docs/angular2/ons-splitter-side.html

Here is the code from the example:

```
window.fn = {};

window.fn.open = function() {
  var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  menu.open();
};

window.fn.load = function(page) {
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  content.load(page)
    .then(menu.close.bind(menu));
};
```

For angular1 and using the sliding menu, these docs are correct:

https://onsen.io/v2/docs/angular1/ons-sliding-menu.html

You would use these methods:

`openMenu([options])` Slide the above layer to reveal the layer behind.

`closeMenu([options])` Slide the above layer to hide the layer behind.

`toggleMenu([options])` Slide the above layer to reveal the layer behind if it is currently hidden, otherwise, hide the layer behind.

Comment: i want to push pages and close menu with ons-navigator, because i am using push pages

Comment: To do that, just simply have 2 lines of code in your function onclick (ng-click).  One to push the page and the next to toggle the menu.  For more help, post some of your code that you are stuck with and we can help you with it.